# Hexagon group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

I was thinking that 
$$\alpha\beta=\beta_6$$ 
$$\beta\alpha=\beta_2$$
$$\beta^2\alpha= \beta_3$$

But I don't know what to do next or is this the right way of solving it,note I have only one example on this topic,,,if there is any link that may help me to learn this topic will be great.

Comment: What is $G$? I guess $A$ and $B$ mean $\alpha$ and $\beta$? What is $B3?$ What is $B6$?

Comment: G = {e,α1,α2,α3,α4,α5,β1,β2,β3,β4,β5,β6}.

Comment: So is the group you are looking at $D_{12}$, the dihedral group of order 12?

Comment: Yes it is D12 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $\alpha$ is the element $(123456)$ and $\beta$ is the element $(12)(36)(45)$. This is disjoint cycle notation of course. We need to prove that $\alpha$ has order $6$, that $\beta$ has order $2$, and that $\beta \alpha \beta = \alpha^5$.

The claims on order are obvious. $\alpha^6 = e$. $\beta^2 = e$.

Now to examine $\beta \alpha\beta$. We have the following permutations given by $\beta\alpha\beta$:
$$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 6$$
$$2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$$
$$3 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2$$
$$4 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 3$$
$$5 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 4$$
$$6 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 5$$

That is to say $\beta\alpha\beta = (165432) = \alpha^5$.

So indeed, $G = \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle \cong D_{12} $.

Comment: Thank you so much,I really appreciate it.